# Set an item to empty in array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

After initialing an array, it contains empty elements. I want to set an element back to empty after setting an value. But it doesn't work however I set it to undefined/null.

```js
var a = Array(20181231);
// it will not run.
a.forEach(e => {console.log(++i + ' - ' + e);});

var i = 0;
a[12] = 12;
a[2018] = 2018;
// it loop twice
a.forEach(e => {console.log(++i + ' - ' + e);});

a[12] = undefined;
// expecting one time, but it still loop twice.
a.forEach(e => {console.log(++i + ' - ' + e);});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) and remove the element of the array.

```js
var a = Array(20181231);
a.forEach(e => console.log(++i + ' - ' + e)); // no loop

var i = 0;
a[12] = 12;
a[2018] = 2018;
a.forEach(e => console.log(++i + ' - ' + e)); // two elements

delete a[12];
a.forEach(e => console.log(++i + ' - ' + e)); // one element
```